# Source that the word לשמי hints to the changing of Yaakov's name to Yisrael

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, vayishlach, jacob

In Genesis 32:30 after Ya’akov want’s to know the name of which he is wrestling with, the question is asked why he wants to know it’s name: (למה זה תשאל לשמי), I can’t find its source but I heard somewhere that the word לשמי is an acronym or combination for the words: לשנות  שמו מיעקב לישראל To change his name from Yaakov to Yisrael.

Looking for a source which confirms this or is similar to it.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.32.30?lang=he&aliyot=1&p2=Bereishit_Rabbah.78.4&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he

Comment: @DannySchoemann Could you be more specific as to what your refering to?